# hi. i'm beginner and i have question regarding sizing a widget in a parent widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

i want to set images into a Center widget, i want to get automatically a size of my center widget and give the half to a child who is an Image widget. I hope my problem is clear to you because i'm also beginner in english. tanks you

Answer (score 0):

you cant use multiple widgets in the center widget use Column or Row and set crossaxisallignment to center